# meaning of positive line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)= (\mathcal{I}_Y)$*

Tags: algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

I am reading Voisin Hodge theory part 2. On page 37 a condition to a theorem (theorem 1.29) is written as: **positive line bundle** $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)= (\mathcal{I}_Y)$*. Y a smooth hyper surface of X= $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$.

She defines $\mathcal{I}_Y$ on page 281 of her part 1 book as: the sheaf of free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of rank 1 given by the holomorphic functions vanishing on $D_i$. $\mathcal{O}_X$ refers to the sheaf of germs of regular functions on X, I think.

Hopefully I've given you enough information.

Is anyone familiar with this notation? How do we go from sheaves to line bundles? What does the * and $\mathcal{O}$ mean?

Comment: Have a look at chapter II.6 in Hartshorne. This holds for any divisor. The $*$ means the dual line bundle.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Algebraic Geometry. How do we go from hyper surface to its divisor? How can $\mathcal{I}_Y$ a sheaf be viewed as a line bundle?

Comment: A hypersurface *is* a divisor.

Comment: @MooS, Weil Divisor, in the notation of Hartshorne?